# Octopus Post Deploy Encrypt Application Settings

Tags: powershell, encryption, octopus-deploy

Does anyone know if there is a tutorial showing how to do encryption of ApplicationSettings in PostDeploy.ps1 when using Octopus for deployment? Or can just show me an example of how the powershell script should look?

EDIT:

Here's an example of the App.config area I want encrypted:

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <configuration>
    <applicationSettings>
        <SmsSurveysWeb.Properties.Settings>
            <setting name="WebSiteUrl" serializeAs="String">
                <value>http://myurl</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="SmsSurveysConnectionString" serializeAs="String">
               <value>Database=MyDatabase;Data Source=MySource;User ID=MyUser;Password=MyPassword;Application Name=My Application;</value>
            </setting>
        </SmsSurveysWeb.Properties.Settings>
    </applicationSettings>
 </configuration>
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample code that you have now and show what parts you want to be encrypted? I don't know anything about octopus but with a better idea of what you want encrypted and how that data is used in the script, and answer might be possible.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <applicationSettings>
    <Properties.Settings>
      <setting name="WebSiteUrl" serializeAs="String">
        <value>http://myurl</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="ConnectionString" serializeAs="String">
        <value>Database=MyDatabase;Data Source=MySource;User ID=MyUser;Password=MyPassword;Application Name=My Application;</value>
      </setting>
    </Properties.Settings>
  </applicationSettings>
</configuration>

Comment: Please edit it into your question, and show how that data is used in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I needed to use the OpenMappedExeConfiguration method.

```
$configurationFileMap = New-Object -TypeName System.Configuration.ExeConfigurationFileMap
$configurationFileMap.ExeConfigFilename = ".\Web.config"

$c =[System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager]::OpenMappedExeConfiguration($configurationFileMap, [System.Configuration.ConfigurationUserLevel]"None")
$s=$c.GetSection("applicationSettings/ProjectName.Properties.Settings")

$s.SectionInformation.ProtectSection("DataProtectionConfigurationProvider")
$c.Save()
```

Comment: I get the error when using the above code. You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression. 
Error
At C:\Octopus\Work\20190503103132-232596-1287\Script.ps1:8 char:1